# Priority Queue in Java

Tags: java, priority-queue

can you have 2 parameters? for instance, i want to add a string and a corresponding integer to a priority key. Then I am going to sort it by that integer. I know how to add either a string or a integer, but I dont know how to add both. Can someone please point me in the right direction and let me know if i am even going about this the right way?

Answer (score 12):

There are two ways to do this. Either way, you want to create a custom object that holds both the String (the value you want) and the integer (the priority).

The first solution is to have this data object implement [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

```
class Data implements Comparable<Data> {
  private final String message;
  private final int priority;

  public Data(String message, int priority) {
    this.message = message;
    this.priority = priority;
  }

  @Override
  int compareTo(Data other) {
    return Integer.valueOf(priority).compareTo(other.priority);
  }

  // also implement equals() and hashCode()
}
```

Then when you do

```
PriorityQueue<Data> queue = new PriorityQueue<Data>();
```

the queue will order items by the order defined by the `compareTo` method.

The problem with this solution is that if you want the ordering to be only on the integer, then either `equals` method and your `compareTo` method will not be consistent or your `equals` method will not be correct.

A better solution would be to use the [PriorityQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) constructor that takes a [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). In this case, `Data` wouldn't have to implement `Comparable`; you just need a `Comparator` that defines your ordering:

```
public final class OrderDataByPriority implements Comparator<Data> {
  public static final OrderDataByPriority INSTANCE = new OrderDataByPriority();

  private OrderDataByPriority() {}

  @Override
  public int compare(Data data1, Data data2) {
    return Integer.valueOf(data1.priority).compareTo(data2.priority);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return other == OrderDataByInteger.INSTANCE;
  }

  private Object readResolve() {
    return INSTANCE;
  }
}
```

Note that since this comparator takes no data, I made it a singleton.

You can then create the queue line this:

```
PriorityQueue<Data> queue = new PriorityQueue<Data>(
    initialCapacity, OrderDataByPrority.INSTANCE);
```

Comment: i am using BUfferedReader to read the input from users.. so they put in the message, then hit enter, then put in the integer(priorty)... now when i do queue.add("string") .. but i need to add them both.. how would i do that?

Comment: i am going to be printing out the strings in descending order.. but its the integer that i will be using to do the comparison... so the integer will need to be connected to the string they entered someway

Comment: You would do queue.add(new Data(message, priority));

Comment: I updated the answer to make it clearer that the integer is a priority and to recommend using Comparator instead of Comparable. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a generic way of doing it:

```
public class PriorityQueue<T> {

    private java.util.PriorityQueue<IntPriorityComparableWrapper<T>> queue;

    public PriorityQueue() {
            queue = new java.util.PriorityQueue<IntPriorityComparableWrapper<T>>();
    }

    public void add( int priority, T object ) {
            queue.add( new IntPriorityComparableWrapper<T>(object, priority) );
    }

    public T get() {
            return (null != queue.peek())? queue.poll().getObject() : null;
    }


    /**
     * A "wrapper" to impose comparable properties on any object placed in the
     * queue.
     */
    private static class IntPriorityComparableWrapper<T>
    implements Comparable<IntPriorityComparableWrapper<T>> {

            private T object;
            private int priority;

            public IntPriorityComparableWrapper( T object, int priority ) {
                    this.object = object;
                    this.priority = priority;
            }

            public int compareTo( IntPriorityComparableWrapper<T> anotherObject ) {
                    return this.priority - anotherObject.priority;
            }

            public int getPriority() {
                    return priority;
            }

            public T getObject() {
                    return object;
            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about creating a **new class** that contains those two fields (`int` and `String`) and then implementing [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) (comparing on the int field). Don't forget to override also `hashCode()` and `equals()` (see the [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) class javadoc for reasoning behind overriding these methods).

Is that what you are after?

Comment: Can you please discuss why he should override `equals()` (and then consequently `hashCode()`)? I would have thought that implementing `Comparable` would have been sufficient.

Comment: See the class Javadoc for Comparable for why you want to override equals() and hashCode()

Comment: Updated my answer with reference to JavaDoc

Comment: @NamshubWriter Can you take a look at my use of PriorityQueue in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800287/how-to-restore-the-priorityqueue-to-its-initial-state-before-the-method-call?noredirect=1#comment45875800_28800287

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use multiple elements as a key, you can create a class that encapsulates both, and then use that type as the key. Likewise for the values. You should make this custom key class `Comparable`, override `equals()`, and override `hashCode()` for the custom key class that you create.

Comment: Can you take a look at my use of a PriorityQueue in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800287/how-to-restore-the-priorityqueue-to-its-initial-state-before-the-method-call?noredirect=1#comment45875800_28800287