# How to restore the PriorityQueue to its initial state before the method call?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, priority-queue

I am doing a practice problem [Practice IT Kth Smallest](http://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/problem.jsp?category=Building%20Java%20Programs%2C%203rd%20edition%2FBJP3%20Chapter%2018&problem=bjp3-18-e9-kthSmallest)

This problem is basically you're passed in a PriorityQueue and a certain k, and you are to return the kth smallest value in that PriorityQueue. You are also to restore the PriorityQueue to its initial state and can use one stack or queue as an auxiliary data structure.

My higher level pseudo thinking is that because the PriorityQueue acts as a min heap already, from [Java PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html), all I really have to do (my algorithm) is:

1. Remove k elements from the PriorityQueue
2. Store the kth smallest value as a local variable
3. Push removed k elements onto a Stack (Stack so I can add elements in the same order)
4. Pop all the elements from the Stack and re add them back into the PriorityQueue
5. Return the kth smallest value

Here is the code to do all of that:

```
public int kthSmallest(PriorityQueue<Integer> pQ, int k) {
    if(k <= 0 || k > pQ.size()) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    } else {
         Stack<Integer> aux = new Stack<Integer>();
         int kThSmallest = -1;
         for(int c=0;c<k;c++){
               int element = pQ.remove();
               if(c == k-1) 
                   kThSmallest = element;
               aux.push(element);
          }
          while(!aux.isEmpty())
              pQ.add(aux.pop());
         return kThSmallest;
      }    
}
```

When I run the program I get all the right outputs, in terms of kth smallest, but I can't restore the state of my PriorityQueue. For example, when passing in a PriorityQueue of:

```
[-3, 9, 17, 22, 42, 81] with a k of 3
```

... my algorithm produces the right result, 17, but it changes the state of the PriorityQueue to `[-3, 17, 9, 81, 22, 42]`, which is unexpected.

I thought about making a copy of the PriorityQueue but that violates one the conditions, "you can use one stack or queue as an auxiliary data structure".

How can I go about restoring the state of the PriorityQueue?

Comment: How do you determine the inner state of the `PriorityQueue`?

Comment: Save everything you removed, and put it back before you exit.

Comment: What makes you think that your current solution is wrong? It seems correct to me.

Comment: @kraskevich try running the code on the site, state of the array changes.

Comment: @EJP Thats what I did with the stack.....

Comment: Which array? If it is obtained by calling the toArray method, it doesn't mean anything because the documentation for the PriorityQueue class clearly states that the elements are returned in no particular order.

Comment: Why do you think making a copy of the PQ violates the conditions?

Comment: @EJP Says 1 auxiliary data structure,  i used one already for storing the removed values.

Comment: @kraskevich i am assuming that the author wants us to think of it as a queue of integers.

Comment: But you don't need the removed values. You only need the Kth removed value.

Comment: @committedandroider I think @kraskevich is right here. It doesn't matter if you use a stack or a queue; a `java.util.PriorityQueue` has only one possible ordering of n integers

Comment: @NamshubWriter How should I preserve the order then?

Comment: @committedandroider the `PriortyQueue` ensures that items will aways be removed in priority order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things need to be adjusted in your implementation. First, you should use a queue, rather than a stack, as your auxiliary data structure. The pushing items into a stack and then popping them back out will result in them being added back into your priority queue *in reverse order*. If they come out of the priority queue as `1, 2, 3`, they'll be added back to the priority queue as `3, 2, 1`. This is because stacks are a LIFO (Last in, first out) data structure. You want to use a queue as your auxilary data structure because it is a FIFO (First in, first out) data structure, so it will preserve the same order.

Second, you only pull the first k elements out of the priorty queue. I would recommend draining the entire queue, so that you're adding all of the elements back into the queue in the order they came out, rather than just some.

In other words, I would adjust your program as follows:

```
public int kthSmallest(PriorityQueue<Integer> pQ, int k) {
    if(k <= 0 || k > pQ.size()) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    } else {
         Queue<Integer> aux = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
         int kThSmallest = -1;
         for(int c=0;c<pQ.size();c++){
               Integer element = pQ.remove();
               if(c == k-1) 
                   kThSmallest = element;
               aux.add(element);
          }
          while(!aux.isEmpty())
              pQ.add(aux.remove());
         return kThSmallest;
      }
}
```

**Note:** I changed the 'element' variable in your program from type `int` to `Integer`. It doesn't matter for the correctness of your program, but it is a good habit to pay attention to auto-boxing. Generic types, like collections, use *boxed* integers. This is an object that stores the primitive integer. Assigning a boxed integer to something of type `int` requires that it be unboxed, i.e. turned back into an `int` primitive. This isn't a big deal, except that you're immediately adding this value back into a collection again. Since you've unboxed it into a primitive `int`, it needs to be boxed back into an `Integer` again, and that requires the system to create an object to store it in. Since all you're doing with the value is taking it out of and putting it back into collections, it's better to use an `Integer` value here, to avoid unboxing and boxing the value, since it isn't really needed.

Comment: How did you come up with the intuition to drain the whole PriorityQueue? LIFO made sense to me because you undo that operation right away. Like you take out 3, 2, 1. Stack would be [3,2,1]. Popping would undo the most recent operation

Comment: I guess the way I look at it is that a PriorityQueue is still a queue. If you take the first k people from line, and put them in the back of the line, you've modified the line, whereas if you take everybody out of the line and put them all back in again, you haven't... So long as, of course, you do it in order.

Comment: But you're putting them back in the line though. You're removing the thing with the most priority. Putting it back will put it back in the same position because it still has the same property that makes it have the most priority?

Comment: I'm not sure why that assumption didn't work in your case. For regular numbers I agree, it *should* work that way. In general, though, you're going to want to drain the queue. Imagine if you had elements with the same priority but a different value, like time off requests prioritized by seniority. Dan and Jim have the same seniority, so they have the same priority. But Dan submitted his request first, so it should be sooner in the queue. You would want to drain the queue so that Dan is still ahead of Jim. That's why I recommended it in this case.

Comment: Ahh I see if you don't drain, original order will not be preserved.